# i have 4 vms in azure how to communicate the one vm to another vm using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

New-AzVm 
    `-ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupVM"`
    -Name "myVM2" 
    `-Location "EastUS"`
    -VirtualNetworkName "myVnet" 
    `-SubnetName "mySubnet"`
    -SecurityGroupName "myNetworkSecurityGroup" 
    `-PublicIpAddressName "myPublicIpAddress2"`
    -ImageName "MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2016-Datacenter-with-Containers:latest" 
    `-Credential $cred`
    -AsJob

Answer (score 0):

they will be able to talk to each other without any additional configurations if they are in the same vnet. if they are in different vnets - you'd need to peer vnets (or create site-to-site vpn). Vnet address spaces have to not overlap in this case.

Comment: thank u but they need with powershell script is this possible?

Comment: i dont understand the question. they would have network connectivity. if something doesnt work - means you misconfigured something